# Sign-up form in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, forms, static-block

I have a web form on a Magento 1.9 website and would like the user to sign-up or login to submit the web-form. How can I can add the sign-up form on a static block? I will then place the static block place it in the web-form.

Static Block code: `{{block type="core/template" template="custom.phtml"}}`

Template custom.pthml file code: `<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ //customer not logged in. Redirect to login page? }else{ //customer is logged in. Show webform from static block or template. } ?>`

Static block in webform HTML block: `{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="5"}}`

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the possible way:

Create a template file where you will check whether customer is logged-in or not. You can call your custom template in your static block like

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom.phtml"}}
```

In `custom.phtml`, check if customer is logged-in or not and call your web-form.

```
 <?php 
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'customer/account/login');
            exit();
        }else{
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_static_block_name')->toHtml();
        }
    ?>
```

Change my_static_block_name with name of your static block.

Comment: Thank you. What is the file path to place the custom.phtml?

Comment: You can create it at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/custom.phtml`

Comment: Ok I placed the file there and I don't see it appear on the form. @amitshrree

Comment: Do you see any output from your file? Can you share your block and template code?

Comment: I don't see an output. I added more detail above in the original question. @amitshree

Comment: @Elvis: I've updated answer. First check if content is appearing from custom.phtml or not by removing everything and echoing Hello.

Comment: I removed everything and echoing Hello does appear on the form, however when I remove Hello and add your updated php code above, the form breaks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38309/discussion-between-elvis-and-amitshree).